# jsPDF does not render html objects

Tags: html, pdf, canvas, jspdf

I´m here with the following problem:

When using jsPDF it should be possible to generate a PDF from HTML code.
The way I'm looking at doing this is with the use of images, I can't seem to get html tables into the pdf the right way (this clears all of the table layouts). While using html2canvas, addHTML plugins the pdf still won't be generated with content. I'm not getting any errors, so I don't know what the problem could be.

Also with the examples given at the link below, the code is written a bit differently, but when I use this code the anomymous function which is passed on as a parameter isn't even executed, therefor I use to following construct.
`pdf.addHTML(document.title, (function() {})());`
Even when this is right, the content won't be shown inside of the PDF.

http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/#

My code has the following three structures which I has tried within the function block:

```
$(function() {
    $('#createPDF').click(function () {

        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
        var options = {
                 pagesplit: true
            };
        pdf.addHTML($('body'), 0, 0, options, (function() {
            pdf.save("test.pdf");
        })());





        var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
        pdf.addHTML('Hallo' ,function() {
            var string = pdf.output('datauristring');
            $('.preview-pane').attr('src', string);
        });
        pdf.save('Test.pdf');




        var doc = new jsPDF();
        window.alert(document.title);
        doc.addHTML(document.title, (function() {})());
        doc.text(20, 20, document.getElementById('learningCurve'));
        doc.text(20, 20, document.getElementById('123'));
        doc.setProperties({ pagesplit: true} );
        doc.addPage();
        doc.text('Do you like that?');
        doc.save('Maandrapportage.pdf');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the save() method only one time.
When using the addHTML() method the remaining code should be placed inside the callback function.
The first addHTML argument must be an  element and not a String (document.title returns a String).

```
  $('#createPDF').click(function () {

       var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
       var options = {
            pagesplit: true
       };

       pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('someID'),0, 0, options,function() {
            pdf.text(20, 20, "put only strings here ...");
            pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('anotherID'),0,50,function() {
                pdf.text(20, 100, "more text here ...");
                pdf.addPage();
                pdf.text(20, 10, "text in another page ...");
                pdf.save("document.pdf");
            });
       });
  });
```